# BEFORE Trigger + RETURNING returns NULL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, partitioning, sql-returning

This is one of the `BEFORE` triggers that inserts into the right [table partition](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_install_session()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.created >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND NEW.created < '2015-10-02 00:00:00') THEN
        INSERT INTO install_session_2015_10_01 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF (NEW.created >= '2015-10-02 00:00:00' AND NEW.created < '2015-10-03 00:00:00') THEN
        INSERT INTO install_session_2015_10_02 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF (NEW.created >= '2015-09-30 00:00:00' AND NEW.created < '2015-10-01 00:00:00') THEN
        INSERT INTO install_session_2015_09_30 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$body$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_install_session
    BEFORE INSERT ON install_session
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_install_session
```

and I have a query that uses `RETURNING`:

```
INSERT INTO "install_session"
  (<columns here>)
VALUES
  (<values here>)
RETURNING "install_session"."id";
```

How can I make the `RETURNING` work? It seems it always returns NULL.

Is it because of the `RETURN NULL` at the end of the function? I can't return `NEW` because the row would be inserted a second time, no? Here is the [official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work with a trigger solution. You could make it work with rules instead of triggers IIRC, but that has other caveats ...

**However**, to just get the auto-generated ID from a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column, you can call [**`currval()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) immediately after the command in the same session:

```
SELECT currval('name_of_your_id_sequence_here'::regclass);
```

Or even just [**`lastval()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) - if respective `id` columns in the partitions are not inherited (don't share the same sequence).

```
SELECT lastval('name_of_your_id_sequence_here'::regclass);
```

You can use [`pg_get_serial_sequence()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to find the name of the sequence if you don't know it:

```
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('install_session', 'id'));
```

Related answer on dba.SE:

- [Return ID from partitioned table in postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58508/3684)

Comment: Would RULES work with PARTITIONS? Unfortunately I can't modify the code that uses RETURNING, so currval() is not an option for me. Thanks for pointing it out though.